# UK visit visa refused for alleged lack of funds. How can I remedy the situation in the future?

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

I applied for UK visit visa on the 23rd of Oct. I got the refusal letter today and I am shocked to see the ECO take an unbelievably strict stance on my application, rejecting my employment evidence, rejecting the affidavit signed by my sponsor and completely ignoring the bank statements of my sponsor (father). I attached my father's salary certificate, evidence of his employment, his bank statements and an affidavit signed by him stating that he would sponsor my trip. The ECO also stated I had no ties to my country when I had specifically mentioned in my cover letter that I am the only daughter of my parents and I live with my mother, while my father lives abroad.
I had attached my bank statements only as proof that I worked and that I had access to amounts other than what my father was providing me with.[image]
I am at a loss as to what to do. Any help would be appreciated.
EDIT: Rejection was from the Abu Dhabi consulate.

Comment: @GayotFow 27 years.

Comment: @GayotFow, any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry for sounding so desperate/anxious. I really wasn't expecting such an outright rejection.

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to go to the UK?  Is there a special purpose for the visit?  If so, did you state it in your application?

Comment: @JohnZwinck, Tourism. Vacation.

Comment: @Gayot Fow, I can only view the chat and not reply, since lack of reputation.

Comment: You see the `random deposits` near you application dates point in the letter, that is always a red flag. You might need to prove your ties to your country emphatically. As you are from Pakistan, a high risk country of people entering illegally into UK, you have to be more emphatic in your proofs.

Comment: @DumbCoder,nice one. that's a votable answer!

Comment: @DumbCoder my bank statements were provided only as support to the bank statements of my sponsor (father) proving I had access to all the funds, mine or his for my trip, and hence I had not thought of proving their origin.

Comment: Can someone please also let me know why my father's statements and sponsorship affidavit were ignored?

Comment: Note: this thread is going to the chat room

Comment: @GayotFow: I don't know where to find the chat room you're talking about.  Anyway, for the OP, my honest advice is to simply not bother trying to visit the UK.  There are plenty of nice places to travel in the world, and most of them are not so paranoid.

Comment: @John: See [chat]